# Can I register multiple HttpSessionListener overrides with Tomcat 8?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

I want to use a third-party session manager library (it's the [AWS DynamoDB lib](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-tomcat-session-manager.html)) with Tomcat 8 (Servlet 3.x). I'd like to include some custom behavior of my own every time a session is destroyed e.g.

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // do it...
    }   
}
```

...and

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>my.package.MySessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

...in addition to:

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Manager className="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.sessionmanager.DynamoDBSessionManager" />
</Context>
```

Will my session destroyed override clobber the AWS session managers own session destroyed override, or vice versa? Or, will Tomcat implement the functionality of both my override and the AWS libraries override whenever a session is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently yes, I can. I've setup the session manager and added the additional session destroyed listener and when I invalidate a session, my own session destroyed code is being run as well as the session manager doing whatever it needs to do.

Presumably you can have as many listeners as you want.